# How to calculate current month and last month values in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as below

[image]

i need to get the output 
Basically it shows what is planned(value) for current month in current month and last month.
[image]

Eg :
in [May16] 201605 what was planned for 201605 as  value 
     and wat was planned in 201604 for 201605 as last month[LM] value

I tried with full outer join query by in case if one month value is missing its not returning the correct result

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where created_month = (select max(created_month) from table);
```

Comment: I have to show All months and the current month planned value and last month planned value..not the latest records

Comment: Basically its for planning Created Month - current month       period-across months im planning the data. value - expected result.So i need to c in 201605 ie may 2016 wat was planned for 201605 as current month and wat was planned in 201604 for 201605 as last month value

Answer (score 0):

You just have to left join the same table by Created_Month and Period.

```
drop table if exists dbo.tMonth;

create table dbo.tMonth (
    Created_Month varchar(100)
    , Period varchar(100)
    , Value int
);

insert into dbo.tMonth (Created_Month, Period, Value)
values ('201604', '201604', 1641)
    , ('201604', '201605', 2458)
    , ('201605', '201604', 6772)
    , ('201605', '201605', 9861);


with cteMonth as (
    select
        convert(date, m.Created_Month + '01', 112) as Created_Month_Date
        , *
    from dbo.tMonth m
)
select
    cm.Created_Month, cm.Period, cm.Value, cmp.Value as LM
from cteMonth cm
    left join cteMonth cmP on cm.Created_Month_Date = dateadd(month, 1, cmp.Created_Month_Date)
            and cm.Period = cmP.Period
order by cm.Created_Month, cm.Period
```